# MS access table operations - suggestions needed

Tags: database, ms-access

I have three tables with similar columns (173 columns in all) - Master, Temp and History.

Master table and Temp table have an ID as primary key. I have to do the following:
1. Compare rows of Master and Temp on ID and find rows that have changed (have different values in atleast one column) between Master and Temp. 
2. If such a row(s) is found, insert the row from Master in History
3. Insert the row from Temp in Master

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

P.S I am using MS Access database

Thanks !

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: 1. What version of Access are you using? 2. Is there any chance to move the data to e.g. the free Sql Server Express? (Then a Timestamp column could be used.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a community of programmers, like yourself, who help each other out because we know what it's like to be new to programming.  We are not a free coding service, we all have jobs or school and help each other out in our spare time.  If you have *specific* questions about *specific* issues, we'll be glad to help!  However, questions like this are generally frowned upon and get closed.  You might want to check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and maybe look at other questions already here to get a feel for what is an acceptable question.

Comment: Hi Shadow,
I have written a query which tries to compare values of all columns if IDs are same. As you might guess, that the query has become very long and is exceeding the limit for query size in Access VBA editor. I am also experimenting with join commands to see if that gets me closer to a solution.

Comment: Hi Andre451,
I am using Access 2013